# Device Id vs. Development Device Id?

Tags: android

What is the difference between Device ID and Development Device ID? Please take note that Device ID is different from Android ID and Telephony Device ID. Also, how do I get the value of both Device ID and Development Device ID programmatically?

Comment: For More Information You have to refer [http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/How-to-retrieve-the-Device-Unique-ID-from-android-device](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/How-to-retrieve-the-Device-Unique-ID-from-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

**Device ID** refers to the serial number — A string created by adb to uniquely identify an emulator/device instance by its console port number. The format of the serial number is -. Here's an example serial number: emulator-5554

**Android Development device id** is yet another manner that your apps can be linked to your phone. Most apps are linked to your account, but some, particularly those that you could not pay for via market, used device id so that you could not buy an app and then install it on several devices.

It used to be hidden only, and maybe after the final is out, it will be hidden again.

for more information - http://androidforums.com/motorola-droid-bionic/584694-ics-development-device-id.html

**Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID** returns the Android ID as an unique 64-bit hex string.

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```